# Rails ActiveRecord/SQL Query best practice

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, activerecord

I've got a table which has the following columns:

- show_days_before_start (integer)
- start_time (DATETEXT)

The purpose of the "show_days_before_start" column is to add the days onto the "start_time" to determine when the record should start appearing in results (if it's outside of this time then it should not be shown) (this column could have value from 7 to 21), and the "start_time" is just a datetime stamp of when the event the record is referring to starts.

I need a query to do the above and to return the relevant records. What is the best way to approach this in terms of query design?

Answer (score 2):

This is the wrong way to do it.
You should generate the show date when inserting the dataset to the database! Add a column called `display_time`:

```
add_column :table_name, :display_time, :timestamp
```

Then in the model you add `attr_reader` and `attr_accessor` for `display_time_reader`

```
attr_accessor :display_time_reader
attr_reader :display_time_reader
```

Then you define the `display_time_reader=` method:

```
def display_time_reader=(days_before_start)
     self.display_time=self.start_time-days_before_start.days
end
```

Then you add a `text_field :display_time_reader` (You can also take a dropdown with values 7..21) to your `_form.html.erb` and when you enter 5 it will save the `start_date` - 5 days to the `display_time` field. Then you could query:

```
ModelName.where("display_time > ?", Time.now)
```

This would be a clean way to deal with this problem!

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm getting the following error `undefined method `days' for "7":String`

Comment: Instead of `self.display_time=self.start_time-days_before_start.days` write `self.display_time=self.start_time-days_before_start.to_i.days`

Comment: Am now seeing this error: `You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.-`

Comment: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wb7acGREdNH2aeuYjye51wwaWdMXgTYvAcNxoDR9HAE=", "sale"=>{"start_time(3i)"=>"13", "start_time(2i)"=>"1", "start_time(1i)"=>"2012", "start_time(4i)"=>"23", "start_time(5i)"=>"00", "end_time(3i)"=>"14", "end_time(2i)"=>"1", "end_time(1i)"=>"2012", "end_time(4i)"=>"01", "end_time(5i)"=>"00",  "display_time_reader"=>"7"}, "commit"=>"create"}`

Comment: that seems to be correct! Please post the whole code of the Model as an answer there must be sth. wrong!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6721/discussion-between-elliot-and-davidb)

Comment: it would appear self.start_time is null, any ideas why?